# Oracle database - ORA-01460 - unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm getting an error message:  unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested using the following code:

```
OdbcConnection oConn = new OdbcConnection();
oConn.ConnectionString = @"Driver={Oracle ODBC Driver};Data Source=*****;UID=********;PWD=******;DBQ=*****;DBA=R;APA=T;FEN=T;QTO=F;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=F;RST=T;FRL=T;MTS=F;CSR=F;PFC=10;TLO=0;";

oConn.Open();

string user = "ANYUSER";
string family = "ANYFAMILY";
DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

OdbcCommand FindCases = new OdbcCommand(@"select TABLE_CASE.ID_NUMBER, TABLE_USER.LOGIN_NAME
                                          from TABLE_CASE, TABLE_USER, TABLE_PRIVCLASS, TABLE_CONDITION, TABLE_PART_NUM
                                          where TABLE_CASE.CASE_ORIGINATOR2USER=TABLE_USER.OBJID and TABLE_CASE.CASE_STATE2CONDITION=TABLE_CONDITION.OBJID and TABLE_CASE.CASE_PRT2PART_INFO=TABLE_PART_NUM.OBJID
                                          and TABLE_USER.USER_ACCESS2PRIVCLASS=TABLE_PRIVCLASS.OBJID and TABLE_USER.LOGIN_NAME=? and TABLE_PART_NUM.FAMILY=? and TABLE_CONDITION.S_TITLE='CLOSED' and TABLE_CASE.CREATION_TIME > to_date(?,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')", oConn);

FindCases.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"user", OdbcType.Text, 4000).Value = user;
FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"family", OdbcType.Text, 4000).Value = family;
FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"date", OdbcType.DateTime, 4000).Value = date;

if (oConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
     try
     {
         OdbcDataReader readCases = FindCases.ExecuteReader(); //errors at this line
```

I have looked around online and the only suggestion I could find was using a to_clob statement. Either I don't understand how it works or that doesn't fix the issue. To my knowledge there shouldn't be any coversion of data types. The 'user' field is text, the 'family' field is text, and the 'date' field is DateTime in the database.

Any ideas are very apreciated!

**UPDATE**
This code works:

```
OdbcCommand FindCases = new OdbcCommand(@"select TABLE_CASE.ID_NUMBER, TABLE_USER.LOGIN_NAME
                                                    from TABLE_CASE, TABLE_USER, TABLE_PRIVCLASS, TABLE_CONDITION, TABLE_PART_NUM
                                                    where TABLE_CASE.CASE_ORIGINATOR2USER=TABLE_USER.OBJID and TABLE_CASE.CASE_STATE2CONDITION=TABLE_CONDITION.OBJID and TABLE_CASE.CASE_PRT2PART_INFO=TABLE_PART_NUM.OBJID
                                                    and TABLE_USER.USER_ACCESS2PRIVCLASS=TABLE_PRIVCLASS.OBJID and TABLE_USER.LOGIN_NAME=? and TABLE_PART_NUM.FAMILY='Desktop' and TABLE_CONDITION.S_TITLE='CLOSED' and TABLE_CASE.CREATION_TIME > ?", oConn);

        FindCases.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"user", OdbcType.Text, 4000).Value = user;
        //FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"family", OdbcType.Text, 4000).Value = family;
        FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"date", OdbcType.DateTime, 4000).Value = date;
```

**UPDATE (AGAIN)**

This code also works perfectly although vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
        OdbcCommand FindCases = new OdbcCommand(@"select TABLE_CASE.ID_NUMBER
                                                    from TABLE_CASE, TABLE_USER, TABLE_PRIVCLASS, TABLE_CONDITION, TABLE_PART_NUM
                                                    where TABLE_CASE.CASE_ORIGINATOR2USER=TABLE_USER.OBJID and TABLE_CASE.CASE_STATE2CONDITION=TABLE_CONDITION.OBJID and TABLE_CASE.CASE_PRT2PART_INFO=TABLE_PART_NUM.OBJID
                                                    and TABLE_USER.USER_ACCESS2PRIVCLASS=TABLE_PRIVCLASS.OBJID and TABLE_USER.LOGIN_NAME=? and TABLE_PART_NUM.FAMILY='" + family + "' and TABLE_CONDITION.S_TITLE='CLOSED' and TABLE_CASE.CREATION_TIME > ?", oConn);

        FindCases.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"user", OdbcType.Text, 4000).Value = user; //field size 30, text
        //FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"family", OdbcType.Text, 4000).Value = family; //field size 20, text
        FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"date", OdbcType.DateTime, 4000).Value = date;
```

**SOLUTION**

I did not realize that 'text' wasn't a true type. Changing to NVARCHAR did the trick:

```
        OdbcCommand FindCases = new OdbcCommand(@"select TABLE_CASE.ID_NUMBER
                                                    from TABLE_CASE, TABLE_USER, TABLE_CONDITION, TABLE_PART_NUM
                                                    where TABLE_CASE.CASE_ORIGINATOR2USER=TABLE_USER.OBJID and TABLE_CASE.CASE_STATE2CONDITION=TABLE_CONDITION.OBJID and TABLE_CASE.CASE_PRT2PART_INFO=TABLE_PART_NUM.OBJID
                                                    and TABLE_USER.LOGIN_NAME=? and TABLE_PART_NUM.FAMILY=? and TABLE_CONDITION.S_TITLE='CLOSED' and TABLE_CASE.CREATION_TIME > ?", oConn);

        FindCases.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"user", OdbcType.NVarChar, 30).Value = user; //field size 30, text
        FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"family", OdbcType.NVarChar, 20).Value = family; //field size 20, text
        FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"date", OdbcType.DateTime, 4000).Value = date;
```

Comment: I took out the 'family' variable and just replaced it with one of the families I'm looking for and it ran as expected. Something must be wrong with the way I'm putting that family variable in but I don't know what it could be

Comment: Your failing example has `family = "ANYFAMILY"`, your successful example has `FAMILY='Desktop'`. It may be worth trying the same family in both approaches, in case the problem depends on the records that are being found by the query. (Oracle often performs implicit casts that work for some values but not others. Comparing a number to a string, for example, will work fine as long as the string can be converted to a number, but will break if it can't.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Some questions, guesses and suggestions...*

What is the exact DDL SQL type for `TABLE_PART_NUM.FAMILY`?

Did you try using `OdbcType.VarChar`, `OdbcType.NVarChar` or even `OdbcType.NText` instead of `OdbcType.Text`?

Also, please note that by default NVARCHAR2 size is in characters but VARCHAR2 is in bytes - maybe "4000" in your code is interpreted as 4000 *characters*, exceeding the maximal field width for character data of 4000 *bytes*. Try using 2000 or even lower number just for testing purposes.

Try to execute the query from the SQL Developer. Do you have any problems there?

Do you use any "unusual" character encoding in your database? You can execute...

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER LIKE '%CHARACTERSET';
```

...and look at `NLS_CHARACTERSET` for VARCHAR2 encoding and `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` for NVARCHAR2 encoding.

What are the exact versions of your ODBC driver and Oracle server? Do they match?

Do you get this problem if you try using the equivalent ODP.NET code?

Answer (score 0):

I *suspect* it's because you're using this:

```
TABLE_CASE.CREATION_TIME > to_date(?,'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
```

which expects a *string* parameter, but you're already passing in a `DateTime` value:

```
FindCases.Parameters.Add(@"date", OdbcType.DateTime, 4000).Value = date;
```

I suspect you can just change your SQL to use:

```
TABLE_CASE.CREATION_TIME > ?
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your suggestion without luck. I've tried just "TABLE_CASE.CREATION_TIME > ?" as well as using my origional statement but changing the type to text:

Comment: @DarkShadow: You shouldn't do any string conversions you don't need to - so the change I've suggested should be your best bet, IMO. You say you tried it "without luck" - does that mean you got the same exception?

Comment: Yes, still getting the same exception when I change to:

TABLE_CASE.CREATION_TIME > ?

Comment: @DarkShadow: I think it would be worth performing a query with *just* `CREATION_TIME` in order to check that that really is the parameter causing problems - basically, simplify things until you've got the simplest possible query which demonstrates the problem, and then it'll be easier to experiment with other options. What's the type of CREATION_TIME?

Comment: Thanks for all the help... the date seems to be OK. I tried the same query but put in a static value for family and it works. Has to be something with the family one but I don't know what.

Comment: @DarkShadow: So can you edit the question to show as short a query as possible showing the problem? (No joins should be required.) What is the type of `TABLE_PART_NUM.FAMILY`?

Comment: TABLE_PART_NUM.FAMILY shows type 'text' in design view editing the database

Comment: @DarkShadow: Right - is that the same as TABLE_USER.LOGIN_NAME?

Comment: @DarkShadow: "Text" is not really an Oracle type. Can you do a `DESCRIBE table_part_num` or a `SELECT data_type FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_PART_NUM' AND column_name = 'FAMILY';`?

Answer (score -1):

Use below sample code. you need to create temporary LOB. this works for me

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;

OracleConnection objConnection = new OracleConnection();
OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand();
try
{
    objConnection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourConnectionString"].ToString();

    if (objConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        objConnection.Open();
    }

    objCommand.Connection = objConnection;

    //Create Temporary LOB @Start
    //Error Without Temp LOB { ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested }
    objCommand.CommandText = "DECLARE dpBlob BLOB; BEGIN DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(dpBlob, False, 0); :tmpBlob := dpBlob; END;";
    objCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("tmpBlob", OracleType.Blob)).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    OracleLob tempLob = default(OracleLob);
    tempLob = (OracleLob)objCommand.Parameters[0].Value;
    tempLob.BeginBatch(OracleLobOpenMode.ReadWrite);
    tempLob.EndBatch();
    objCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    //Create Temporary LOB @End

    objCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT_BLOB";

    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("IN_USERNAME", "Sample Name");
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("IN_UPLOADED_BY", "Sample Name");

    string excelFileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    int intlength = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

    Byte[] byteData = new Byte[intlength];
    FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(byteData, 0, intlength);

    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("IN_ATTACH_FILE_ORIGINAL", excelFileName);
    objCommand.Parameters.Add("IN_ATTACH_BLOB_ORIGINAL", OracleType.Blob).Value = tempLob;

    objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    objCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    if (objConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        objConnection.Close();
}
```