# Mass Update in Oracle via stored procedre

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have to do a mass update. So I have wriiten a procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE or_doh_rcause_sm_wip_upd_sp ( 
   p_rcause_cd   VARCHAR2,  
   p_doh_sa           clob 
)
IS
v_plant_cd              VARCHAR2 (8);
v_doh_sa                NUMBER          := 0;
v_ins_upd               CHAR(1);
Begin
for i in (select regexp_substr( p_doh_sa, '[^;]+', 1, rownum) result
          from dual
         connect by level <= length(regexp_replace( p_doh_sa, '[^;]+')) + 1)
   LOOP
    v_doh_sa     := TO_NUMBER(substr( i.result||',', 1, instr(i.result,',')-1 ),'9999999999999999999') ;
    v_ins_upd    := substr(i.result, instr(i.result,',',1)+1,1);
    v_plant_cd   := substr( i.result,instr(i.result,',',1,2)+1 );

IF v_ins_upd = 'U' THEN

           update OR_DOH_PM_SM_ROOT_CAUSE_T set ROOT_CAUSE_SA = p_rcause_cd 
           where DOH_SA = v_doh_sa
           AND   Plant_cd = v_plant_cd;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Eg:p_doh_sa:'942168,I,FV52;942167,I,FV52;';

Like this i will have more than 500 sets. When from the front end if they run

getting error `ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested`

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Could you post a value of: `p_doh_sa clob` passed to the procedure ? Without it it is hard to say what was a reason of this error. Most likely the function `to_number` tried to convert some value that was not a number.

Comment: Is this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8141398/1940685

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR` on a `CLOB` will return a `CLOB`. `SUBSTR` on a `CLOB` will also return a `CLOB`. But `TO_NUMBER` [will not work on a CLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions211.htm#sthref1685) . So you should add a `TO_CHAR` which always return a `VARCHAR2` and that should do the trick.